# Numpy - compute all possible differences in an array at fixed distance

Tags: python, numpy, difference

Suppose I have an array, and I want to compute differences between elements at a distance `Delta`. I can use `numpy.diff(Array[::Delta-1])`, but this will not give all possible differences (from each possible starting point). To get them, I can think of something like this:

```
for j in xrange(Delta-1):
    NewDiff = numpy.diff(Array[j::Delta-1])
    if j==0:
        Diff = NewDiff
    else:
        Diff = numpy.hstack((Diff,NewDiff))
```

But I would be surprised if this is the most efficient way to do it. Any idea from those familiar with the most exoteric functionalities of `numpy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following function returns a two-dimensional numpy array `diff` which contains the differences between all possible combinations of a list or numpy array `a`. For example, `diff[3,2]` would contain the result of `a[3] - a[2]` and so on.

```
def difference_matrix(a):
    x = np.reshape(a, (len(a), 1))
    return x - x.transpose()
```

### Update

It seems I misunderstood the question and you are only asking for an the differences of array elements which are a certain distance `d` apart.<sup>1)</sup>

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,7,11,13,17,19])
>>> d = 2
>>> a[d:] - a[:-d]
array([6, 8, 6, 6, 6])
```

Have a look [at the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to learn more about this notation.

But, the function for the difference matrix I've posted above shall not be in vain. In fact, the array you're looking for is a diagonal of the matrix that `difference_matrix` returns.

```
>>> a = [1,3,7,11,13,17,19]
>>> d = 2
>>> m = difference_matrix(a)
>>> np.diag(m, -d)
array([6, 8, 6, 6, 6])
```

<sup>1) Judging by your comment, this distance `d` is different than the `Delta` you seem to be using, with `d = Delta - 1`, so that the distance between an element and itself is 0, and its distance to the adjacent elements is 1.</sup>

Comment: I am not sure I understand this code, but it seems to me that this is doing something else. It is computing differences between neighbours. The purpose here is different: given a distance `Delta`, I want to compute all differences. So, let's say I have a vector `[1,3,7,11,13,17,19]` and `Delta=3`. I want to get `[6,8,6,6,6]` (the order is irrelevant)

Comment: @AJC Okay, I've misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer accordingly. Previously, it only answered the more general case for all possible distances, not for a given one.

Comment: Indeed, why did I complicate my life with numpy.diff?